# ubuntu 14.04 does not boot after fresh installation

Tags: 14.04, uefi, acer, boot-repair

I instlled ubuntu 14.04 on an acer e5-573-36uy laptop in uefi mode. The installation went fine but i am unable to boot into ubuntu. I tried boot-repair from a live usb here is the paste http://paste.ubuntu.com/12515019/. some error was flashing very fast on the screen so i captured a screen from the video https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEAJY.jpg with this ?

Answer (score 1):

You're running into some variety of Secure Boot error. My hunch is that your computer lacks the keys needed to boot Ubuntu; or possibly there's a bug involved, probably in your EFI's Secure Boot implementation. (I've seen some computers refuse signed copies of Shim, which is the tool that Ubuntu uses as a Secure Boot solution.) It could also be that you've got some odd mixture of signed and unsigned copies of GRUB.

The easiest workaround is to disable Secure Boot. Unfortunately, details of how to do this vary from one computer to another. [This page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) shows four examples of how to do it, but I've heard descriptions of some that vary significantly from any of mine.

Comment: Yeah I disabled secure boot to get it working.